# Selenium: Could not open connection: Error forwarding the new session cannot find Capabilities for Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, testing, selenium

I am trying to run Behat tests on Internet Explorer.

In my Windows 7 VM I start

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node -hub  
    http://myhostcomputer:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=ie 
    -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer.exe
```

Which starts successfully and registers to my Linux host:

```
16:07:26.582 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@104c47b5
16:07:26.598 INFO - using the json request : {"class":"org.openqa.grid.common.Re
gistrationRequest","capabilities":[{"seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","platform":"V
ISTA","browserName":"ie"}],"configuration":{"port":5555,"register":true,"host":"
192.168.0.188","proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy","brow
ser":"browserName=ie","maxSession":5,"role":"node","hubHost":"x.orange.imi.local
","registerCycle":5000,"hub":"http://myhostcomputer:4444/grid/register","Dwe
bdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer.exe":"","hubPort":4444,"url":"http://192.168.0.
188:5555","remoteHost":"http://192.168.0.188:5555"}}
16:07:26.598 INFO - Starting auto register thread. Will try to register every 50
00 ms.
16:07:26.598 INFO - Registering the node to hub :http://x.orange.imi.local:4444/
grid/register
```

I have `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role hub` running on `myhostcomputer`. And I get messages that when the node  connects:

`org.openqa.grid.internal.BaseRemoteProxy <init>`

When starting `behat` I get

```
 Could not open connection: Error forwarding the new session cannot find :
     Capabilities [{platform=VISTA, browserVersion=11, ignoreZoomSetting=false, 
     browserName=ie, deviceType=pc, name=Behat Test, selenium-version=2.41.0, 
     browser=ie, deviceOrientation=portrait, version=11, max-duration=300}]
```

What is wrong here? Can I list the capabilities which are available in the Selenium server?
I already tried to replace all *ie* with *iexplore*.

Comment: Share your java code for the Capabilities settings

Answer (score 1):

Parameters allowed for -browser are browserName={android, chrome, firefox, htmlunit, internet explorer, iphone, opera}

So change it to `internet explorer`

Ref - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Comment: When setting it to `internet explorer` the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your capabilities are using the same data types for all your requested capabilities.

I was seeing a similar problem and it turned out my nodes were using integer versions, and my code was asking for string representations of the numbers.

Changing either one to match the other will fix the problem.

i.e. use `"version":11` with `DesiredCapabilities.setCapability("version",11)` or use `"version":"11"` with `DesiredCapabilities.setVersion("11")`

Comment: Also, according to https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration, IE 11 isn't supported yet.